# users are not able to query one specific table in the azure sql database - getting Error Code 8630

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm hoping someone else may have encountered this and been able to resolve. I'm presently waiting for an azure support tech to help, so figured I'd reach out here in the mean-time since I couldn't find anything online...

I have a read-only database that users can query all tables without issues except for one specific table. Azure recommended solution pointed to login to user mapping issues, however, that would not allow the user to access the database which is not the case here.

There are no long running queries or open transactions and the server is more or less idle. I'm not seeing any locking or blocking either, so this is quite puzzling to me.

I can reproduce the issue with all users of all types testing with:
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.{table 1} - results in no issues

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.{table 2} - gets following error

Msg 40197, Level 20, State 200, Line 3
The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 8630.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 1
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: Computed column?  Does table 2 have any computed columns?

Comment: no computed columns, not a wide table and no large datatypes for columns.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, Azure Support had me scale up and scale down the database and that has resolved the issue.